# How to find the function $\phi(u)$ fullfills the condition

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, curves

I am facing problem in computing the function $\phi(u)$ such that the normal unit vector of the curve is parallel to the plane XY.
The curve is 
$$\vec{r}=(a \cos(u), a \sin(u), \phi(u))$$
thanks in advance if any one will help properly.

Comment: What have you tired?

Comment: @GuyFsone sir i found the unit tangent vector but the claculation to find the unit normal are so lengthy.....
i am acually facing problems in calculations

Comment: @NoorAslam  I Guess a is a parameter not a variables? right?

Comment: @GuyFsone I know that a is constant not variable but still you know sir calculations are so lengthy

Answer (score 1):

First find the tangent vector $\mathbf{t} = \frac{d\vec{r}}{du}/ ||\frac{d\vec{r}}{du}||$ for your curve and then find the unit normal by 
$$
\vec{n} = \frac{\mathbf{\dot{t}}}{||\mathbf{\dot{t}}||}, \quad \text{with}  \quad \mathbf{\dot{t}} = \frac{d\mathbf{t}}{du}
$$
for $\vec{n}$ to parallel to $XY-$plane, then its $z-$component must be zero. You can find $\phi(u)$ from above condition.

$\textbf{EDIT :}$

There are many (families) of such curve. One quick (non trivial) guess that probably work is $\phi(u) = au+b$.

Comment: Your guess is (to the best of my knowlodge) wrong. Consider $\alpha(t) = (\cos(t), \sin(t), t)$. You also seem to be assuming that the curve has unit speed, which isn't necessarily true here and can't be assumed without loss of generality.